# General function to return Id

Tags: c#

In my project i've written my own mappers, and there's a lot of places where I'm doing things like
`tbl.Type != null ? tbl.Type.Id : 0` to return the id of referenced objects.
Because this is occuring so many times, I'm trying to make a small function that does this check for me, no matter the type of object I pass.

I was thinking along the lines of

```
public static int returnId(object input)
{
    if(input != null && input.Id != null)
    {
        return input.Id;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

or maybe using generic type `<T>`.

Currently this function throws errors because `object` doesn't contain a definition for `.Id`. I've been googling around for a few hours now, and start to wonder if what I'm looking for is even possible.

Any help and ideas are welcome and much appreciated!

Comment: Is `object` always a custom type?

Comment: `object` would be classes I have defined

Comment: In C# 6 you can use `tbl.Type?.Id ?? 0`

Comment: I wish I'd known that `?.` was a thing earlier. Would have saved me a lot of trouble. I'll be using that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All *inputs* should implement `IId` interface:

```
public static int returnId(IId input)
{
    if(input != null && input.Id != null)
    {
        return input.Id;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or via reflection:

```
public static int returnId(object input)
{        
    if(input != null)
    {
        var Id = input.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(input);
        if(Id != null)
            return ((int?)Id).Value;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need for generics there.

Comment: Nice, people usually do not see the need for interface, when its staring at them

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1: Use `dynamic` instead of `object`:

```
public static int returnId(dynamic input)
{
    if(input != null && input.Id != null)
    {
        return input.Id;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

2: Have all your classes inherit from an interface that defines `id`:

```
public static int returnId(IId input)
{
    if(input != null && input.Id != null)
    {
        return input.Id;
    }
    return 0;
}

public interface IId
{
   int Id {get; set;}
}
```

The 2nd option should have better performance, because [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) requires the operation to be resolved at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is not feasible in the general case. If you want to be able to retrieve an object's Id you need to ensure that property Id exists in every type you would use with your method.

In most cases the best option would be to follow Slava's original suggestion, namely (with minor enhancements)

```
public interface IId
{
    int Id {get;}
}

public static int returnId<T>(T input) where T : IId
{
    return input != null ? input.Id : 0;
}
```

Using dynamic and reflection (e.g. input.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(input)) would have a similar effect, but 
1) it provides no compile-time guarantees - all validation is done at runtime and will fail if the type has not property named "Id";
2) runtime logic has negative impact on performance, which would be visible during intense usage.

Inheritance, as suggested by @hofmeister is an option only when you only need to apply this method to types defined by yourself, not any third-party classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use inheritance and implement the `Id` property for each of your class. Something like this:

```
public abstract class ObjectId
{
    // Or as auto-propert `public virtual int Id { get; private set; }`.
    public abstract int Id { get; }
}

public class ObjectImpl : ObjectId
{
    public override int Id
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }
}
```

In addition to this implementation, you can define a default value (as virtual property) for your base class. As a result, not every class has to override the property `Id`.

With this implementation, you can pass the `ObjectId` as input type to your function and return `0` if it's `null`.

```
public static int returnId(ObjectId input)
{
    return (input != null) ? input.Id : 0; // input.Id will never be null.
}
```

Comment: why should `Id` be abstract?

Comment: @nozzleman I don't know anything about the derived classes. With the abstract property every class has it's own implementation.

Comment: Yeah, I see, I'd assume that every `class` will probably implement this using an auto-property, so making it a `virtual` auto-property would still allow overriding it in the rare cases another implementation is needed. An `abstract class` with only an `abstract` property is basically an `interface`. Other than that, an abstract class would make sense, if the OP chooses to make all required classes implement it ;)

Comment: @nozzleman Indeed, but I mentioned the default implementation (auto-property) as well. Without any details about the objects we can only guess the best implementation.